# Profiling C + Python (SWIG)

Tags: python, c, profiling

I have python code with C libraries, I use SWIG to plug it all together. I would like to profile the C libraries.

I compiled them with `-pg` but no profiling output is generated... Is there method to profile such a mixed code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) with the [Callgrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cl-manual.html) module (built-in). This will produce a file that can be displayed in KCacheGrind, which is avaliable on most Linux distributions.

To limit profiling to just your code, use the [limiting collection options](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cl-manual.html#cl-manual.limits), this will allow Python to run at almost full speed, and only profile your code (which will run about 10x slower).

Note: I haven't tried this with Python myself, but it has worked for similar situations.